# Code written after infinite loop executes

Tags: java

The following code shows an empty `infinite loop` and code written after the loop prints "Hello, World".

In this example, the `println` statement to print the statement `synchronously` and thus theoretically, after the `infinite loop` nothing should be printed, but still when on running the code, it prints "Hello, World".

So, why is the code written after an infinite loop executing?

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0; i>=0; i++){}
        System.out.println("Hello, World"); // This is printed on the console
    }
}
```

I tried searching goole and stackoverflow for it, but could not find an answer for the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Consider putting a print statement in that loop. See what number it actually gets to and see if there's any significance to the stopping point.

Comment: Alternatively declare `i` outside of the loop and print `i` after the loop to see its value.

Comment: Why do you believe that is an infinite loop? Do you believe that an `int` value can somehow count to infinity?

Comment: you should take a look at what a integer overflow and underflow is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop is not an infinite loop. It goes until the `i` reaches `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Then `i` becomes `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which is a negative value. Run the code below and check the output.

```
int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
x++;
System.out.println(x);
```

If you want the loop to be infinite use,

```
for ( ; ; ){
}
```

Answer (score 7):

When i becomes greater than max value(2147483648 - that can be represented in 32 bits), it overflows to its min value.
It runs exaclty Integer.MAX_VALUE times, because Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 is Integer.MIN_VALUE, a negative number.

You can visualize your code like this :

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i>=0; i++){}
    System.out.println("Hello, World : "+ i);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Either the compiler smartened up and knew that nothing was done in that loop (which shouldn't matter, because even the for conditions can edit stuff)

or `i` looped 2 million something times and overflowed into negative numbers, making it less than 0.